# C# console Application Proxy authentication not working

Tags: c#, authentication, proxy

Please assist with the code below.

When I use it on a Pc that doesn't require a proxy and the proxy settings are commented out it works fine but now I have to run the program on a proxy enabled network but it continuously gives me the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll Additional information: The remote server returned an
>   error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Please note if you try to run the program it wont be able to fetch the data as it needs to be run from  a PC whose IP is on the white lists.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 
using System.Net; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace ConsoleApplication1 
   { 
      class Program
     { 
         static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        string urlDemo = "http://www.api.myoptions.com/api"; 
    // ReadCountries(); 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlDemo);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matt.luck", "Mambo88e","JOC");
    WebProxy aProxy = new WebProxy();
    aProxy.Address = new Uri("Http://182.155.1.205:8080",true)

    request.Proxy = aProxy;

    // Set the Method property of the request to POST. 
    request.Method = "POST"; 
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array. 
    string postData = "api_username=usernameapi_password=password";
    postData += "&MODULE=Customer&COMMAND=view&FILTER[id]=1";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest. 
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest. 
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; request.Timeout = 60000; 
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
    // Write the data to the request stream. 
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
    // Close the Stream object.

    // Get the response. 
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status. 
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription); 
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server. 
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access. 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content. 
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    // Display the content. 
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer); 
    Console.WriteLine("\nClick On Enter To Close Window");
    Console.ReadLine();
    // Clean up the streams. 
    reader.Close(); 
    dataStream.Close(); 
    response.Close(); 
   } 
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your proxy details are correct and provide the credentials to the *WebProxy* object

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlDemo);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matt.luck", "Mambo88e","JOC");
WebProxy aProxy = new WebProxy();
aProxy.Address = new Uri("Http://182.155.1.205:8080",true)
aProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matt.luck", "Mambo88e","JOC");
```